# Windows shutdown script is not running

Tags: windows-10, batch-file, script, shutdown

I have a simple .bat script that i would like for windows to run when shutting down

*shutdown script .bat*

```
@echo off
title Shutdown script
curl --silent --output nul --show-error --fail -m 0.5  --digest "http://192.168.0.158/shutdown
```

I am using `group policy > Computer Configuration > Windows settings > Scripts > shutdown > script > add > C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine\Scripts\Shutdown\shutdown script.bat`

When i shutdown the computer nothing happens. I can confirm that the script is working because double clicking the script executes it no problem.

I have also tried using the `group policy > User Configuration > Windows settings > Scripts > logoff > script > add > C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\User\Scripts\Logoff\shutdown script.bat`

and still the same thing it does not execute when i shut down the computer. Any ideas?

Comment: "C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine\Scripts\Shutdown\shutdow script.bat" the filename is wrong. You're missing an `n` from `shutdown` this could also be an 8.3 issue. Try calling the file `shutdown.bat`

Comment: @spikey_richie the missing 'n' is a typo in this post, i have edited the post. The actual path is correct. What is a 8.3 issue?

Comment: Can you try to replace the `curl` command by something like `echo test > C:\Users\Public\test.txt`, then check if the file is created after shutdown ?